# How correctly store .js files to Localstorage of a browser

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Can you please tell me how can I correctly store some js file to localstorage and then run it.

So I have found some code that stores an image, but can I store a js file?

Here is the code:

https://gist.github.com/robnyman/1875344

```
// Getting a file through XMLHttpRequest as an arraybuffer and creating a Blob
var rhinoStorage = localStorage.getItem("rhino"),
    rhino = document.getElementById("rhino");
if (rhinoStorage) {
    // Reuse existing Data URL from localStorage
    rhino.setAttribute("src", rhinoStorage);
}
else {
    // Create XHR and FileReader objects
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        fileReader = new FileReader();

    xhr.open("GET", "rhino.png", true);
    // Set the responseType to blob
    xhr.responseType = "blob";

    xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            // onload needed since Google Chrome doesn't support addEventListener for FileReader
            fileReader.onload = function (evt) {
                // Read out file contents as a Data URL
                var result = evt.target.result;
                // Set image src to Data URL
                rhino.setAttribute("src", result);
                // Store Data URL in localStorage
                try {
                    localStorage.setItem("rhino", result);
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.log("Storage failed: " + e);
                }
            };
            // Load blob as Data URL
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
        }
    }, false);
    // Send XHR
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem when you try to store a different kind of file? But anyway why do you want to do this? I'm trying to think of a use case

Comment: local storage is just a string based system to store long strings without any form, so i don't think you can save a js file in it but you can save JSON init if you want in form of string

Comment: i dont know i just want to know if is it possible? if i can store a js file, can i store js script code?